# Wrong table names format - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue with the table names format of my Django project.

Here is a sample of a model I have:

```
class WalletHistory(models.Model):
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wallet_history')

    free_amount = AmountField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    locked_amount = AmountField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    flexible_amount = AmountField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

The app associated with this model is called `core` so the table name is supposed to be `core_wallet_history`. But Django names my table `core_wallethistory` instead: it doesn't split the class names with underscore.

I've changed nothing in the Django settings.

Comment: this is the default naming convention https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#table-names

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't post comments yet as I don't have enough reputation.

How are rendering your tables?

I use django-tables2 and all I have to change is the attributes via the class Meta under the table.

Example:

```
class offer_table(ExportMixin,tables.Table):
   offer_name = tables.Column(accessor='offer_name')
   class Meta:
        attrs = {"name":"offer_table", "id":"offer_table",}
```